Why does the pi bond in ClO₂ form from 1 p electron and 1 d electron instead of both d orbitals?
In chlorine dioxide (ClO₂), there is an odd electron which does not participate in hybridization. The hybridization of the chlorine atom in ClO₂ is sp², leading to the formation of 2 π bonds.
After sp² hybridization, 3 electrons remain, with 2 electrons forming π bonds with oxygen atoms. These electrons are sourced from 1 p orbital and 2 d orbitals (following the excitation of chlorine).
Since it is known that dπ-pπ bonding is generally stronger than pπ-pπ bonding, it would be expected that both π bonds should form using d orbitals. However, the observed bonding pattern is one π bond formed from a p orbital and the other from a d orbital.
My question is:
Why does the π bond in ClO₂ form from one p orbital and one d orbital instead of using both d orbitals, even though dπ-pπ overlapping is stronger than pπ-pπ overlapping?

This question is similar to: Hybridisation of ClO2. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
